# Commutator subgroup, abelianization and what else to determine a group?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-extensions

If one knows the commutator subgroup $[G, G]$ and the abelianization $G/[G, G]$ of a group $G$, what else is needed to determine the group? If $G$ is a central extension of a group $H$, $G$ is determined by $Z(G)$, $H$ and a cocycle. Is there a corresponding theory for extensions with a given commutator subgroup?

For example, is it possible to define a group operation on $[G, G] \times G/[G, G]$ so that the resulting group is isomorphic to $G$, as it happens for central extensions?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun I disagree with the proposal of discouraging questions "that are nothing besides a problem statement" and I do not see how I can improve my question. I searched in books and on the web and I did not find anything useful, so I am asking experts what work on this question has been done. I believe the question is clear and I gave the central extensions case to explain what kind of answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It is natural that extensions $E$ fit a sequence
$$0\to [G,G]\to E\to G/[G,G]\to0,$$
and  these $E$ are classified by homomorphisms
$$G/[G,G]\to {\rm Out}[G,G]$$
where ${\rm Out}[G,G]=\dfrac{{\rm Aut}[G,G]}{{\rm Inn}[G,G]}$.

Comment: Thanks. This is true for any normal subgroup, right? I was hoping that the particular case of the commutator subgroup could lead to more information.

Comment: it is enough a subgroup be  normal for the quotient be a group